# packet drops at application port level

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I am trying to identify if there are any UDP packet drops while receiving messages, because of my application not processing them in time.

So I would like to know packet drops at the application port level.
My application is listening on port 5018 (this is my application port.)

I would also like to mention that I checked the following command. 
I checked in the file  /proc//net/udp

the last column **drops**. Would that be the column which will provide dropped packets info at the application port level

other commands like ss, netstat, ip, ethtool they all do not seem to provide info port level. Let me know if there any other commands or procedures for me to know dropped packets dues to application at a port level.

Comment: What is `application port level` ? Are you referring to when the packet is dropped by the system before it ever hits the wire?  Why is this information more relevant than end to end reliability of the UDP packet (which can get dropped by many other places before it arrives at the destination).

Comment: UDP is an inherently unreliable transport protocol. If you need reliability, then you use a reliable transport protocol, e.g. TCP, or you build the reliability into your application.

Comment: @selbie , I just re-edited my question. I understand UDP does not provide reliability.  I am just trying to see I need to improve the performance of my application (for eg: increasing SO_RCVBUF or anything like that.) So before doing that I want to see the symptoms of RX messages dropping. Hence the question, by using which linux command I will be able to find it.